# Magento 2 : Minicart always showing loader after product add to cart?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax, mini-cart

When I am clicking on **Add To Cart** button then product was added to my cart and mini-cart count also updated but loader on mini-cart showing always.

[image]

After refreshing my page mini-cart shows updated count.

[image]

What should I do to remove that loader after mini-cart count update?

**Update:**
Below is response of add to cart ajax call:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console that is preventing the javascript from stopping the loader after it is started?

Comment: @LM_Fielding Thanks for your reply. No error in my browser's console tab.

Comment: Check by changing deploy mode to PRODUCTION and enable cache.

Comment: Check the network tab on developer tools, the XHR to find the request for adding a product to cart, it may not be completing (staying at pending due to lag?)

Comment: @LM_Fielding I have added response in my question(200 OK).

Comment: same issue on my site, but the above code is not working. Please provide me with some other solutions.(thanks)

Comment: not sure for latest code now @user115061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add to cart** Ajax call is given in below js file:

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

So we need to override it in your theme like following:

```
/app/design/frontend/custom_package_name/custom_theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

Following is default ajax call where we need to add some code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
                }
            },
            success: function(res) {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
                }

                if (res.backUrl) {
                    window.location = res.backUrl;
                    return;
                }
                if (res.messages) {
                    $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
                }
                if (res.minicart) {
                    $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                    $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
                }
                if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                    $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                        .removeClass('available')
                        .addClass('unavailable')
                        .find('span')
                        .html(res.product.statusText);
                }
                self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
            }
        });
    },
```

Add below code in beforeSend() function:

```
          /*To hide loader on mini-cart*/
            $(".loading-mask").show();
            /*****************************/
```

Add below code in success() function:

```
       /*To hide loader on mini-cart*/
             setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loading-mask").hide();
             }, 3000);
        /*******************************/
```

Like below:

```
beforeSend: function() {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
                }
                /*To hide loader on mini-cart*/
                $(".loading-mask").show();
                /*****************************/

            },
success: function(res) {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
                }

                if (res.backUrl) {
                    window.location = res.backUrl;
                    return;
                }
                if (res.messages) {
                    $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
                }
                if (res.minicart) {
                    $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                    $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
                }
                if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                    $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                        .removeClass('available')
                        .addClass('unavailable')
                        .find('span')
                        .html(res.product.statusText);
                }
                /*To hide loader on mini-cart*/
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".loading-mask").hide();
                }, 3000);
                /*******************************/
                self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
            }
```

I have used **setTimeout()** function to stop loader after mini-cart count increament.

Answer (score 0):

To hide **loader** count at **minicart**.

Copy file from

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/js/view/minicart.js**

to your theme

**app/design/frontend/{{VENDOR}}/{{THEME}}/Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var sidebarInitialized = false,
        addToCartCalls = 0,
        miniCart;

    miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']');

    /**
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    function initSidebar() {
        if (miniCart.data('mageSidebar')) {
            miniCart.sidebar('update');
        }

        if (!$('[data-role=product-item]').length) {
            return false;
        }
        miniCart.trigger('contentUpdated');

        if (sidebarInitialized) {
            return false;
        }
        sidebarInitialized = true;
        miniCart.sidebar({
            'targetElement': 'div.block.block-minicart',
            'url': {
                'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
                'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
            'button': {
                'checkout': '#top-cart-btn-checkout',
                'remove': '#mini-cart a.action.delete',
                'close': '#btn-minicart-close'
            },
            'showcart': {
                'parent': 'span.counter',
                'qty': 'span.counter-number',
                'label': 'span.counter-label'
            },
            'minicart': {
                'list': '#mini-cart',
                'content': '#minicart-content-wrapper',
                'qty': 'div.items-total',
                'subtotal': 'div.subtotal span.price',
                'maxItemsVisible': window.checkout.minicartMaxItemsVisible
            },
            'item': {
                'qty': ':input.cart-item-qty',
                'button': ':button.update-cart-item'
            },
            'confirmMessage': $.mage.__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?')
        });
    }

    miniCart.on('dropdowndialogopen', function () {
        initSidebar();
    });

    return Component.extend({
        shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,
        maxItemsToDisplay: window.checkout.maxItemsToDisplay,
        cart: {},

        // jscs:disable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
        /**
         * @override
         */
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this,
                cartData = customerData.get('cart');

            this.update(cartData());
            cartData.subscribe(function (updatedCart) {
                addToCartCalls--;
                // this.isLoading(addToCartCalls > 0);
                sidebarInitialized = false;
                this.update(updatedCart);
                initSidebar();
            }, this);
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function () {
                addToCartCalls++;
                // self.isLoading(true);
            });

            if (
                cartData().website_id !== window.checkout.websiteId && cartData().website_id !== undefined ||
                cartData().storeId !== window.checkout.storeId && cartData().storeId !== undefined
            ) {
                customerData.reload(['cart'], false);
            }

            return this._super();
        },
        //jscs:enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers

        isLoading: ko.observable(false),
        initSidebar: initSidebar,

        /**
         * Close mini shopping cart.
         */
        closeMinicart: function () {
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        closeSidebar: function () {
            var minicart = $('[data-block="minicart"]');

            minicart.on('click', '[data-action="close"]', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
            });

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} productType
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getItemRenderer: function (productType) {
            return this.itemRenderer[productType] || 'defaultRenderer';
        },

        /**
         * Update mini shopping cart content.
         *
         * @param {Object} updatedCart
         * @returns void
         */
        update: function (updatedCart) {
            _.each(updatedCart, function (value, key) {
                if (!this.cart.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.cart[key] = ko.observable();
                }
                this.cart[key](value);
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Get cart param by name.
         * @param {String} name
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getCartParam: function (name) {
            if (!_.isUndefined(name)) {
                if (!this.cart.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    this.cart[name] = ko.observable();
                }
            }

            return this.cart[name]();
        },

        /**
         * Returns array of cart items, limited by 'maxItemsToDisplay' setting
         * @returns []
         */
        getCartItems: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];

            items = items.slice(parseInt(-this.maxItemsToDisplay, 10));

            return items;
        },

        /**
         * Returns count of cart line items
         * @returns {Number}
         */
        getCartLineItemsCount: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];

            return parseInt(items.length, 10);
        }
    });
});
```

What we had done is commented the line

> **this.isLoading(addToCartCalls > 0);**

and

> **self.isLoading(true);**

If it helps please upvote.
Thanks for your time to read the answer.